# While using Inheritance property, the derived class does not take the data members of the template base class. Why is that and how can it be solved?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

The base class here is Rectangle and it is a template class. I have derived a class called ColorRectangle from Rectangle and it is also a template class. But ColorRectangle cannot access the protected data members of Rectangle. How can I solve this?

Rectangle header file

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Rectangle{
protected:
    T length;
    T breadth;
public:
    void setLength(T len){
        length = len;
    }
    void setBreadth(T bre){
        breadth = bre;
    }

    T getLength(){
        return length;
    }
    T getBreadth(){
        return breadth;
    }
    T area(){
        return length*breadth;
    }
};
```

ColorRectangle Header file

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Rectangle.h"
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class ColorRectangle:public Rectangle<T>{
  private:
    T borderWidth;
    string borderColor;

  public:
    void setBwidth(T bw){
        borderWidth = bw;
    }
    void setColor(string bc){
        borderColor = bc;
    }
    T calcPerimeter(){
        return 2 * (length + breadth);  
    }
};
```

Comment: In inherited class, you do `this->param` to access parent member `param`.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members